# Laravel: Cannot end a section without first starting one

Tags: laravel

The following is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.systemmain')
@section('title','New Product')
@section('content')
{{Form::open(['files'=>'true','action' => 'Product@store'])}}
@include('system.product.form',['mode' => 'New'])
{{Form::close()}}
@endsection
@section('pagejavascript')
<script>
    //$('#nav7').addClass('active');
</script>
@endsection
```

1. I've tried using @stop but doesn't work.
2. I'm using Mac, so could it be something related to that?
3. Even when i deleted all the @section & @endsection, the error still pops up (i did use php artisan cache:clear)
4. I used the same but slightly modified code on other add.blade pages and they have no problems.
5. Currently using laravel 5.8.

Comment: The first section (*'title'*) is not closed, maybe try to close it before?

Comment: you are missing a `@endsection` after `@section('title','New Product')`

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: can you provide your layout and/or the include file? ... this error sounds like something is calling `@stop` or `@endsection` that should not be as there are no open sections at that point

Comment: @lagbox I'm using Laravel 5.8 (I seem to have problem updating to the latest version)

Comment: @lagbox What do you mean by providing layout? (sry I'm new to this haha)

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your first section:

```
@section('title','New Product')
```

So your sections are overlapping. You have to close one section before you start another.

Comment: you can define a section in this way, the second argument would be the content https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: Ah ok, til. Can you post your error or maybe tell us about your expected vs actual behavior?

Comment: The error is as in the title. If there's no error it's expected to enter a "Create Product" page. But now it's just stuck on the error page on localhost :(